# Convert string to dateresults in an "out of range" error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a date stored as `21-06-2019` in column of type `varchar(50)` in a SQL Server table.

I am trying to read it as date like this:

```
select convert(datetime, process_date) dt 
from cardx1
```

But I get this error:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.. Native error: 242. SQLSTATE: 22007. Severity 16. MsgState 3. Line 1.

Please help.

Comment: The real question is why is your column a `varchar(50)` and not a date and time data type? Fix the design, fix the problem.

Comment: The documentation for convert explains how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably not using the correct datetime style. See [Date and Time styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)

```
select convert(datetime,process_date,105) dt from cardx1
```

Should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `try_convert()`:

```
select try_convert(datetime, process_date) as dt
from cardx1 ;
```

To find the problem values:

```
select process_date
from cardx1
where try_convert(datetime, process_date) is null and
      process_date is not null;
```

Note:  Your real problem is that you are storing dates as strings in the database.  The data should go in as a `date` so you don't have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your current language setting is probably EN_US causing default US date formats (MM/dd/yyyy).
To override this in the current query you can add a "date style number",
e.g.
`select convert(datetime,process_date,103) dt from cardx1`

For further reading, i'd recommend the following article:
https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-functions-for-converting-string-to-date/